# Is there a standard suite of tools for testing gpfs file systems?

Tags: filesystems

I'm looking for something that acts like a benchmark ('is the filesystem slow?') and for something to detect problems, errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPFS comes with some tools to do that, try looking for `gpfsperf` or `nsdperf` depending on what you want to test those tools could help you..
They should be in `/usr/lpp/mmfs/samples/perf`

Comment: a link to a more detailed explanation would be useful, perhaps even an example.